# Does consumption of alcohol cause hair loss?

Tags: alcohol, hairloss, deficiency

I am wondering if alcohol consumption causes hair loss/baldness?

Although I'm not bald, I'm only curious to know that if at a later stage of life, would I get bald for alcohol consumtion? I read that alcohol consumption causes iron and zinc deficiency, that help in hair growth.

So, my question is, is alcohol bad for hair growth at a later stage in life?